# np.logical_and operator not working as it should (numpy)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dataset (ndarray, float 32), for example:

```
[-3.4028235e+38 -3.4028235e+38 -3.4028235e+38 ...  1.2578617e-01
  1.2651859e-01  1.3053264e-01] ...
```

I  want to remove all values below 0, greater than 1, so I use:

```
 with rasterio.open(raster_file) as src:
            h = src.read(1)
            i = h[0]
            i[np.logical_and(i >= 0.0, i <= 1.0)]
```

Obviously the first entries (i.e. -3.4028235e+38) should be removed but they still appear after the operator is applied. I'm wondering if this is related to the scientific notation and a pre-step is required to be performed, but I can't see what exactly. And ideas?

To simplify this, here is the code again:

```
    pp = [-3.4028235e+38, -3.4028235e+38, -3.4028235e+38, 1.2578617e-01, 1.2651859e-01,  1.3053264e-01]
    pp[np.logical_and(pp => 0.0, pp <= 1.0)]
    print (pp)
```

And the result

```
pp = [-3.4028235e+38, -3.4028235e+38, -3.4028235e+38, 0.12578617, 0.12651859, 0.13053264]
```

So the first 3 entries still remain.

Comment: i = ?. What do you mean by "removed"? Please make a small but complete example, showing your code.

Comment: I can not reproduce this, If I run this locally, I get `array([0.12578617, 0.12651859, 0.13053264])`.

Comment: Note that here you do *not* remove the elements from `i`, you construct a *new* array that is filtered.

Comment: @WalterTross: I updated my code snippet. Basically the array is coming from an raster array (from a .tif image).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: yes you're right, my choice of words was lousy.

Comment: You must be confused somehow, your code is fine, the problem is in code you aren't showing us.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: I get the same, except the first entry (see my updated post).

Comment: @pymat: again, you do not change `pp`, you construct a new array, so your line `pp[...]` has no *effects* at all.

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake, I had to wrap the array in a numpy array, then assign a variable to the new constructed array, like so:

```
    j = np.array(pp)
    mask = j[np.logical_and(j >= 0.0, j <= 1.0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not removing the indices you selected. You are just selecting them.

If you want to remove them. You should probably convert them to nans as such

```
from numpy import random, nan, logical_and

a = random.randn(10, 3)
print(a)
a[logical_and(a > 0, a < 1)] = nan
print(a)
```

Output example

```
[[-0.95355719         nan         nan]
 [-0.21268393         nan -0.24113676]
 [-0.58929128         nan         nan]
 [        nan -0.89110972         nan]
 [-0.27453321  1.07802157  1.60466863]
 [-0.34829213         nan  1.51556019]
 [-0.4890989          nan -1.08481203]
 [-2.17016962         nan -0.65332871]
 [        nan  1.58937678  1.79992471]
 [        nan -0.91716538  1.60264461]]
```

Alternatively you can look into masked array